# Draytek router port usage?

Tags: router, port, gigabit, draytek

We have a Draytek router which is connected to our primary switch (Nortel) using the lAN port (which is also the port labelled 4). I noticed that there is a port reserved for gigabit Ethernet.

Should the LAN be plugged into the gigabit poet rather than the LAN port if I use the gigabit port on the Nortel switch?

Will this allow more bandwidth to the router? If so, i will have to remove one of our servers from the gigabit ports on the switch. Is it a sensible sacrifice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The router connects you to the internet. Unless you have a 1Gbps internet connection then connecting the 1Gbps ports between the router and the switch isn't going to do you any good.

Comment: I guessed as much but wondered if it would improve "data-flow" to the router. On reflection that probably doesn't make any sense! Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help...

Answer (score 1):

If you have one gigabit to work with on a switch, it is a good idea to use that for your highest traffic item on that switch because it probably ties into the backbone of the switch. Sometimes this is a server (say a file server that sees a lot of traffic). Other times it will be your uplink to another switch.

**EDIT:** In your case it sounds like a high speed uplink will not gain you anything because you are only using it as a connection to an even lower speed network. You should keep your internal LAN going at full gig speed. (Credit for @joeqwerty for noticing these details)